# Help With: $2(2^x- 1) x^2 + (2^{x^2}-2)x = 2^{x+1} -2$

Tags: calculus

I have this problem, $2(2^x- 1)x^2 + (2^{x^2}-2)x = 2^{x+1} -2$, but am stuck on how to solve it. I need to find all off the real solutions, but I have really no idea how to start. I noticed that it is a quadratic (kind of) if you move all the terms to one side, with $2(2^x- 1)$ being a, $(2^{x^2}-2)$ being b, and $-2^{x+1}+2$ being c. 
I still want to find the answer by myself, so can anyone help point me in the right direction? 
Thank you.

Comment: $x = \{-1,0,1\}$

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}$

> Lemma 1: $$\sign(2^z-1)=\sign(z)$$

*Proof:* $2^z-1$ is strictly increasing and $2^0-1=0$.

> Lemma 2: $$(2^a-1)b+(2^b-1)a=0\iff ab=0$$

*Proof:* By lemma 1, $\sign\left((2^a-1)b+(2^b-1)a\right)=\sign(ab)$.

> Claim: $$x=0,\pm 1$$

*Proof:* By algebraic manipulation, the original becomes:

\begin{align*}
2(2^x-1)x^2+(2^{x^2}-2)x&=2^{x+1}-2\\
(2^x-1)x^2+(2^{x^2-1}-1)x&=2^x-1\\
(2^x-1)(x^2-1)+(2^{x^2-1}-1)x&=0
\end{align*}

Therefore by lemma 2, $x(x^2-1)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$2(2^x- 1) x^2 + (2^{x^2}-2)x = 2^{x+1} -2 \iff 2(2^x- 1) x^2 + (2^{x^2}-2)x - 2(2^{x} -1)=0$$

$$(2^x- 1) (x^2-1) + (2^{x^2-1}-1)x =0 \iff (2^{x}-1)\cdot g(x)=-(2^{g(x)}-1)\cdot x$$

then

- for $x=0 \implies g(x)=x^2-1=-1 \implies LHS=RHS$
- for $0<x<1 \implies g(x)=x^2-1<0\implies LHS<0$ and $RHS>0$
- for $-1<x<0 \implies g(x)=x^2-1<0\implies LHS>0$ and $RHS<0$
- for $x=\pm 1 \implies g(x)=x^2-1=0\implies LHS=RHS$
- for $x>1 \implies g(x)=x^2-1>0\implies LHS>0$ and $RHS<0$
- for $x<-1 \implies g(x)=x^2-1>0\implies LHS<0$ and $RHS>0$

Answer (score -1):

Here's the graph of $2(2^x -1)x^2+(2^{x^2}-2)x - \left( 2^{x+1} - 2\right)$

[image]

$$x = \{ -1, 0, 1\}$$

Clearly the $x 2^{x^2}$ term dominates for large $|x|$, and guarantees that there are no more solutions, i.e., the set stated is maximal.

Comment: Graph of what? Also your graph does not provides the maximality of the given solution set.